# K&R: Array of pointers to strings with newlines

Tags: c

I have a small issue with an K&R example (sort line example, page 108).

I do not understand the behaviour I see when I uncomment the line in **readlines** which removes the newline character added when reading input with **getline**.

```
int main()
{
    int nlines;

    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
        my_qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("error: input too big \n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len, nlines;

    char *p, line[MAXLEN];

    nlines = 0;
    while ((len = my_getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if (nlines >= maxlines || (p = alloc(len)) == NULL)
             return -1;
        else {
            line[len-1] = '\0'; //delete newline. 
            my_strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
        }
    return nlines;
}

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    while (nlines-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
}
```

For example, if I then pipe in the following:

```
linje1
linje2
linje3
linje4
```

then **writelines** will output:

```
linje1
linje2
linje3
linje4

linje2
linje3
linje4

linje3
linje4

linje4
"and one last newline..."
```

From which I deduce that lineptr[0] points to all the lines. lineptr[1] points to all but the first line, ... , lineptr[3] points just to "linje4"

I do not understand how we get this behaviour from storing lines as "linje1\n", instead of "linje1".

Clarification:
in writelines (when `lineptr` points to the start of the array)
how can the call `printf("%s", *lineptr)` print all the lines?

**Edit 2**:

Ah, I see, but here is the getline function from K&R

```
int my_getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

And I was sure that would always give me a null-terminated string, regardless of whether it ended with a newline or not?

and here is K&R's alloc:

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; // Storeage for alloc
static char *allocp = allocbuf; // Next free position

char *alloc(int n) // Return pointer to n characters
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) { // it fits
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

**Edit 3**:
Thank you for all the comments. But the entire program is typed up exactly as in K&R and works perfectly (I have compared the output with *grep*), so all the peripheral functions do as intended (my_strcpy for example works exactly like strcpy and copies the string up to and including the null terminator). The *alloc* function is just a pointer to K&R's big *char* array.

What I still don't understand is:

C reads in some lines of text, copies it, which stores line *i* somewhere in memory, and have `lineptr[i]` point to that memory location:

The lines are read with *my_getline*, which reads in the entire line (including newline character) and then terminates the string with the nullcharacter.

If I skip the `line[len-1] = '\0';` step, *readlines* then stores a pointer to a copy of this line in `lineptr[i]`. And in memory, I thought the string (for i=1) looked like this `"linje1\n\0"`

But as @DanJAB pointed out, the nullcharacter is most likely missing, so the string is stored as `"linje1\n"`, and so when *writelines* prints (via the pointer in the first entry in *lineptr*) this line, it prints everything following this in memory, since the nullcharacter is missing, which happens to be the rest of the lines.

But what I just can't wrap my head around is why is `line[len-1] = '\0';` then evidently is needed for the string (i=1) to be stored as `"linje1\0"`, when *my_getline* always returns a nullterminated string?

Thanks again, and sorry for any potential unclarities.

**Final edit**
The entire problem was with alloc(len) not allocating space for the final nullcharacter! Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: perhaps the issue with the null terminator being missing otherwise is in another function. Perhaps `my_strcpy` is not doing it correctly.

Comment: @DanJAB No I get exactly the same if I replace that function with the library version. Thanks though.

Comment: What type/value is `MAXLEN`?

Comment: A basic debugging technique is to use print statements.  For example, after the line: `line[len-1] = '\0'; //delete newline.`, you could add: `printf("line: <<%s>>\n", line);` to check that the newline has been zapped.  Of course, if there wasn't a newline, you've zapped some other last character, but that shouldn't be an issue with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) With `char line[MAXLEN]; ... my_getline(line, MAXLEN) ... my_getline(char s[], int lim)`, `lim` is the *size* of the buffer.

But the function `my_getline()` is designed that `lim` is the maximum string *length*.
C string *length* is 1 less than the minimum *size* needed for that `char` array to resides in.

Use `char line[MAXLEN+1];` or alternatively change `my_getline(line, MAXLEN)` code to `i < lim-2`

2) The result of `my_getline(line, MAXLEN)` can be `""` (but the `len > 0` test takes care of that) , further the line may not end with a `'\n'`.

```
line[len-1] = '\0'; //delete newline.
```

Better to use

```
if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') {
  line[len-1] = '\0'; //delete newline. 
}
```

3) `p = alloc(len)` is inadequate.  Use `p = alloc(len+1u)`

4) Recommend commenting out `my_qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);` until all other code is working.

5) All this makes me suspect the unposted `my_strcpy()/my_qsort()` too.

Code may have additional problems, but what is posted in not compilable.

Comment: Yes, I see it's important to keep one's tongue straight.  If for example the last line is not a blank line, but a line of text, then "line[len-1] = '\0'" will zap that lines last character, for example turing "linje4" into "linje"

Comment: The entire missing nullcharacter behaviour  got fixed when doing alloc(len+1) instead ! I finally get it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the line `line[len-1] = '\0';` It's not deleting a new line, it's replacing it with a null terminator. This means that if you don't have that line then you don't have the that thing that marks the end of the string, therefore when you print it, you also get whatever follows it in memory (the next strings).

Comment: But I thought that getline (as K&R as written it) always returns a null terminated string? So when I get a string from getline, I though it had a '\n' at the end, but is still null-terminated?